# Twigs not responsive on Android device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm trying to make a responsive website with Symfony using media queries (in my own stylesheet but also with bootstrap).

I use twigs in this project, and those queries don't affect chrome using my Android phone (which isn't really old either). They do, however, work on chrome from a pc.
Weird thing is, if I use a PHP page instead of a twig, the queries do work on Android.
Hence I suppose that the problem comes from the twigs.

From what I've understood there's 2 main options to me:

- First is to put my queries inside the Twig using < style > *media queries* < /style >.
- Second would be to make specific stylesheet for mobiles and tablets and use the MobileDetectBundle to say which stylsheet use.

The problem is that while the first wouldn't be pretty (and don't seem to work anyway), the second would reduce my media queries to 2 sizes (mobile and tablet) for mobile devices, while I use more (ie: to reduce the text's size on a really small device, etc).

Is there a better workaround or even a reason for this to happen that I missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide some code to demonstrate how you are including your assests?

Comment: probably not twig's fault. Twig is a template engine, his job is to build html. Your html/css in guilty, not twig.

Answer (score 0):

Twig is a template engine. It will not deal with responsive design.
It a CSS problem.

If you want do the second option, you can use the [suncat/mobile-detect-bundle](https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle) like it's [explained in the doc.](https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#twig-helper)

Answer (score 0):

As hungerstar suggested, it simply was my assets' declaration that wasn't right.
I'm even surprised that only the media queries weren't displayed and that everything else was positioned correctly.

In case anyone else encounter this silly problem, here's my code that now works on android devices

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link [...]/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks a lot!